# MS Word table -macro to find row containing specific text then move entire row to last row in the table

Tags: vba, ms-word

Looking to create a macro that will search down MS Word table, find a specific word, then move that entire row to the bottom of the table, then repeat for the next occurrence of that word.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to write any code for the macro yourself yet?

Comment: The way you have worded your question, you could get yourself into an endless loop in the first table a specific word was found. I suggest rewording/rethinking the requirements of you macro. i.e. First match creates new table row and then search moves to the next table.

Comment: @ Rich: The way I read the Q, there could be multiple matches in a single table, only one of which is mentioned. Not too hard to implement.

Comment: Please take a moment to read the site guidelines in the [help] about how to effectively ask questions on Stack Overflow. Note that you are expected to show your research and the code you have. Questions should be specifically targeted. This is neither a free code-writing service nor a tutorial site.

Comment: Cross-posted at: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?63327-Word-macro-to-find-specific-text-and-move-entire-row
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 0):

The specs you've given @ vbaexpress are somewhat different to what you gave here. Assuming the vbaexpress specs are correct, try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim TblRng As Range, TmpRng As Range
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
  Set TblRng = .Range: Set TmpRng = .Range
  With .Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = "DENIED"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Format = False
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = True
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
      If .InRange(TblRng) Then
        TmpRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        TmpRng.FormattedText = .Rows(1).Range.FormattedText
        .Rows(1).Delete
      End If
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
  If .Rows.Count > TblRng.Rows.Count Then
    .Split .Rows(TblRng.Rows.Count + 1)
  End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Note:** the above code assumes you're processing just the first table in the document; if it's a different table, change the 1 in .Tables(1) to suit.