# Word table find paragraph break, split row content in to two row

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-table

The word tables having variable number of rows and columns.
The below code I have taken from previously answered in this forum and try to modify it. However, due lack of knowledge I could find or able to edit it further.

Few rows in table having paragraph break (¶) marked in yellow color in image and in same row few texts with space marked in green color.

I have try to find rows for paragraph break. If found, add row below and split content in to two rows. Below images, explain details. The below table images presented by Turn formatting marks on.

First row having variable width. Hence, find from row 2 to last rows, as remaining rows are similar. The first three columns remains constant.

[image: Before]

[image: Expected]

similar post found but not split row content ([MS Word table -macro to find row containing specific text then move entire row to last row in the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623728/ms-word-table-macro-to-find-row-containing-specific-text-then-move-entire-row-t)). I have try to find "^p".

The 4 to last column having paragraph break in any row. The new row added after and duplicate content of above row and then split. The column 1 to 3 have space between text.

Similar post [Moving down a row in a Word table containing multi-paragraph cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327072/moving-down-a-row-in-a-word-table-containing-multi-paragraph-cells?noredirect=1&lq=1)
But not working in mixed width table.

```
Sub FindParagraph()
With ActiveDocument.Range
With .Find
.ClearFormatting
.Replacement.ClearFormatting
.Text = "^p"
.Replacement.Text = " "
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindStop
.Format = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.Execute
End With
Do While .Find.Found
If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then

'Don not know code.



End If
.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
.Find.Execute
Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try recording the actions for which you don't have code in a macro to get a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt the macro recorder will be much help here. Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Tbl As Table, r As Long, c As Long, bFnd As Boolean
For Each Tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
  With Tbl
    For r = .Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
      With .Rows(r).Range.Find
        .Text = " "
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Text = "^p"
        .Execute
        bFnd = .Found
      End With
      If bFnd = True Then
        .Rows.Add .Rows(r)
        For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
          If .Cell(r + 1, c).Range.Paragraphs.Count > 1 Then
            .Cell(r, c).Range.Text = Split(.Cell(r + 1, c).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
            .Cell(r + 1, c).Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
          End If
        Next
      End If
    Next
  End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Sir, Thank you very for your time and effort. Macro working perfectly. To avoid searching of " ". I have first replace SP.P with SP ^p P, meters with meters^p. Then change .Text = " " with .Text = "^p" in macro. Result produce by above macro as expected. Once again thank you very much sir.

Comment: «To avoid searching of " ". I have first replace SP.P with SP ^p P, meters with meters^p. Then change .Text = " " with .Text = "^p" in macro.» The macro, as coded by me, already does all that is required. You could have left it alone...